# How to set keycloak endpoints -- cookie not found (HA - cluster) setup

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am running a problem with cookie not found with keycloak. Looking at the issue I found this article which is similar to my problem. [Issue on keycloak - cluster - cookie not found](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/cookie-not-found-ha-gcp-load-balancer/14967/2).

uiqa is the front end server. extqakc is the cluster setup address. I am not sure why the authorization endpoint is different then token-endpoint host. I get this data by posting to the cluster address. https://extqakc.xxx.com/secauth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration

How are these values setup such as authorization_endpoint. I am not seeing anything on the front-end interface. Running on keycloak 17. Thanks.

```
{
    "issuer": "https://uiqa/secauth/realms/myrealm",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://uiqa/secauth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "token_endpoint": "https://extqakc.xxx.com/secauth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://extqakc.xxx.com/secauth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://extqakc.xxx.com/secauth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://uiqa/secauth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
```